# Automatic Labels with automatically generated keys

Tags: macros, labels, expansion, expl3, detokenize

I am writing a collection of documents in book form, one each for 4-5 topics. Each book has upwards of 30 chapters each in a different file. The books must be able to cross reference each other since they all are intended for the same end purpose. In every book, some of the chapters are independent of other chapters and can be rearranged at a later date. Obviously chapter number in labels is useless. I want string based label keys for each chapter/section of each book. I cannot manually generate all those keys with a consistent naming scheme.

I use a regex based string compactifier for this purpose. Not being an expert on TeX/LaTeX, this forum has been of great help to me ([Unsigned integer variable in a regex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376224/unsigned-integer-variable-in-a-regex)). Each chapter should get a label of the form math:mod:first_chapter and sections should be labeled math:sec:first_chapter:section_name. A custom chapter/section command is used for automatic labeling.

In my MWE, I am just including the case for chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse,expl3,l3regex}
\usepackage[outer]{showlabels}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\compactlabel}{O{20}m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {[^a-zA-Z\s]} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_once:nnN {\A\s+} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_once:nnN {\s+\Z} {\ } \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {\s+} {_} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {(^\w{1,#1})\w*} {\1} \l_tmpa_tl
    \regex_replace_once:nnN {_\Z} {} \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \str_lower_case:f { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \explower \tl_lower_case:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\subjectshort}{Compsci} % unique for each book
\newcommand{\chaplabel}[1]{
    \expandafter\label\expandafter{\explower{\subjectshort}:mod:#1} % works but not desirable
    %\expandafter\label\expandafter{\explower{\subjectshort}:mod:\chaplabel{#1}} % does not work but desirable
}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{ \chapter{#1} \chaplabel{#1}}

\begin{document}

\mychapter{First Chapter}

Some text
\end{document}
```

While creating labels, compacted names do not work. I have tried using multiple `\expandafter`s and `\detokenize` to get it work. I always get the error : missing endcsname in the aux file. It is driving me crazy. What is going wrong here? How do I make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Imho such automatic labels are nonsense. If you decide e.g. to translate your book and change "First Chapter" to "Premier chapitre" all your references will fail. Using the chapter text for automatic labels is for the same reason useless as in your argument against numbers: it is not stable enough. Better write some macro for your editor which creates a \label when you insert \chapter the first time.

Comment: I agree: an automatic label is the same as no label as far as the user is concerned. There are uses for automatic labeling, but just for internal workings of macros the user has no control upon.

Comment: why use such a complicated scheme? if you obfuscate the label generation in this way you need to use the same obfuscation every time you use `\ref` why not simply use a normal `\abel` or if that is really inconvenient, just use the entire section title.

Comment: I do not contest that it is a massive overkill. However it is not useless since I frequently forget to label a section (or chapter) and when I need it, have to hastily cook up a unique label. This hasty label often has names like hamiltonxxtt, which is impossible to remember and can be used only with tools like `\usepackage{showlabels}`. I am anyway going to have a proliferation of labels so I might as well label each and every section even if it is an overkill.

Comment: @Magguu but why obfuscate the label so much that you would need a function to generate the `\ref`  why not just use the section title?

Comment: The section title frequently contains math and other symbols. I wanted pure un-spaced text as my keys, though not strictly necessary for my purposes. The prefixes help me in quickly identifying which book/chapter/section they are coming from. Handy when I am looking at the files a few years down the line. Hence an algorithmic generation of keys.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Using `\ref` is no trouble as I anyway copy-paste the keys from `\usepackage{showlabels}`-generated PDF. The real pain comes when I myself open my latex files after a few years and I have no idea about the ad-hoc label-keys.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do like follows, but I don't think this is really useful.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
%\usepackage{l3regex} % not for releases after June 2017
\usepackage[outer]{showlabels}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\generatechapterlabel}{O{20}m}
 {
  \magguu_compactlabel:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \label{\str_lower_case:f { \subjectshort }:mod:\l_magguu_compactlabel_tl}
  \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_magguu_currentchapterlabel_tl \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\generatesectionlabel}{O{20}m}
 {
  \magguu_compactlabel:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \label
   {
    \str_lower_case:f { \subjectshort } : sec :
    \g_magguu_currentchapterlabel_tl :
    \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
\tl_new:N \g_magguu_currentchapterlabel_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \magguu_compactlabel:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl { #2 }
  % remove non alphabetic/space characters
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[^a-zA-Z\s]} {} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % remove words less than three letter long
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b} {} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % remove leading spaces
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {\A\s+} {} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % remove trailing spaces
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {\s+\Z} {\ } \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % change runs of space into an underscore
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\s+} {_} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % truncate to #1 characters
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {(^\w{1,#1})\w*} {\1} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % remove a possible trailing underscore
  \regex_replace_once:nnN {_\Z} {} \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl
  % lowercase the string
  \tl_set:Nx \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl { \str_lower_case:f { \tl_use:N \l_magguu_compactlabel_tl } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\subjectshort}{Compsci} % unique for each book

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1}\generatechapterlabel{#1}}
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\section{#1}\generatesectionlabel{#1}}

\textwidth=5cm % just to see the labels

\begin{document}

\mychapter{First Chapter}

Some text in chapter~\ref{compsci:mod:first_chapter}

\mysection{First Section}

Some text in section~\ref{compsci:sec:first_chapter:first_section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just perfect. Thanks a lot. Let me say again - this overkill is NOT useless for me. Actually I do not really understand the expl3 syntax but I just summoned up the cargo cult spirit in me and copy pasted it :)

Comment: @Magguu The compact version of the current chapter title is saved in a token list that can be used for sections; it will only change at the next `\mychapter` command.