# Redefine Section to include Hypertarget and tooltip

Tags: hyperref

I would like section and subsection to automatically create a hypertarget (for external url linking into the pdf) and a pdftooltip, that displays the url (so the url is discoverable)

```
\section{\pdftooltip{Common Pressed Meats}{\#Common-Pressed-Meats}}\hypertarget{Common-Pressed-Meats}{}
\hypertarget{Canned-Pressed-Spam}{\subsection{\pdftooltip{Canned \& Pressed Spam}{\#Canned-Pressed-Spam}}}
```

Either of these lines work for me, my question us how to redefine `\section` and `\subsection` so that `\section{Common Pressed Meats}` will output one of the above, and to do the conversion from heading text (with symbols) to valid url without symbols,
[Damn they almost work - pdfbookmark ia "Common Pressed Meats#Common-Pressed-Meats"]

Here is MWE for pdflatex

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=section,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{\pdftooltip{Common Pressed Meats}{\#Common-Pressed-Meats}}\hypertarget{Common-Pressed-Meats}{}

The hypertarget is Common-Pressed-Meats or from the internet http://www.spam.com\#Common-Pressed-Meats

\hypertarget{Canned-Pressed-Spam}{\subsection{\pdftooltip{Canned \& Pressed Spam}{\#Canned-Pressed-Spam}}}

Invalid and special URL chars (i.e. most symbols) in the heading text
must be removed from the hypertarget and replaced with dash -

\hypertarget{Other-Pressed-Meats}{\section{\pdftooltip{Other Pressed Meats}{\#Other-Pressed-Meats}}}

The tooltip is over the heading text, and shows the hypertarget preceded
by \#
\end{document}
```

**What am I trying to do and Why?**

I have documentation, in pdf, on the net. It is detailed and typically 5-50 pages long. When dealing with technical queries part of the answer is in the documentation. I need to be able to send a link that goes directly to the part of the document that explains my point. The link (url from internet, or Named-Destination in pdf terminology) needs to be human meaningful, and my answer should still be useful in 3 months time when the document has been revised (which rules out "section.2.1.3". Me and any other users need to quickly an easily know what the url is when reading the pdf. This is why have tootip. Otherwise the named destinations are too difficult to be useful
Note that I am not interested in using the hypertarget internally within the latex/pdf

Comment: Imho such automatic labels are seldom useful -- when you rename the section every link will break. But beside this check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376450/automatic-labels-with-automatically-generated-keys

Comment: take a look to my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578 it redefines all kinds of sections for almost all classes. You may add your commands above evrey `\oldsection` call all bellow it and you may also include it inside an hyperlink. I will try to understand what you want to do and if possible I will write an answer.

Comment: I agree that automatic labels are not ideal, but what hyperref currently does is this:  section.8 ,  subsection.8.1 ,  page.11 , which is probably as utterly useless as it is possible to acheive

Comment: `hyperref` already adds automatic hyper targets. It does not use a symbolic name for them but a section-leve-prefix, e.g., `subsection` followed by a dot and the section number, e.g., [`subsection.3.6` in the `hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf#subsection.3.6)

Comment: The anchor for a section is `section.1` etc. the number `1` is replaced by the total section number (unless the section number is reset). The same is almost true for any other structure level counter,, where the higher levels are appended,  i.e. subsection.1.1

Comment: The existing hyperref targets are simply useless for two reasons:(a) almost every edit will move them, and (b) they are meaningless to the reader www.spam.com/meat.pdf#Canned-Pressed-Spam is better than www.spam.com/meat.pdf#subsection.1.1

Comment: The automatic labels of hyperref are for internal processing, e.g. for the link from the bookmarks to the section -- it doesn't matter if they change or are meaningless. But for external links you need a name that is stable. So better use manual \label/\hypertarget.

Comment: They might be used internally, but hyperref exports them as the pdfs NamedDestinations. (i.e. external urls}, so they are not just internal use. It would be nice to suppress this, as an 11 page document has 123 useless named-destinations to confuse things

Comment: BTW to see the named destinations in a pdf, use this: https://pdfresizer.com/list-named-destinations

Comment: @HenryCrun I am trying to understand what you want to do but I don't use windows too... So can not test tooltip and your goal. Would just an automatic link (with `\href`) that works on your section and subsection header be ok? And if so... what would be the url for every section or subsection? do you have to give it with every sectioning command (as a second argument) or it has to be something fixed using the title?

Comment: I have added Why? to the end of my question. It is external urls into the pdf, not internal cross-references in the latex that I want. i.e www.spam.com/meat.pdf#Canned-Pressed-Spam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want more symbolic anchor names, you can use the extended optional argument feature of KOMA-Script (see option `headings=optiontotocandhead` in the examples below) and add a new key to generate the hyper targets:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotocandhead% Switch on extended optional arguments for headings
]{scrartcl}[2017/04/13]% Need at least KOMA-Script v3.23
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DefineFamilyKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{hypertarget}{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\section[hypertarget={First.Section.Name}]{First Section Name}
\lipsum[1]
\section[hypertarget={Example.Section}]{Example Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section[hypertarget={Final.Section}]{Final Section}
See \hyperlink{First.Section.Name}{the first section} or
\hyperlink{Example.Section}{the second section} or
\hyperlink{Final.Section}{this final section}.
\end{document}
```

To also add a tool tip you could try something like:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontotocandhead% Switch on extended optional arguments for headings
]{scrartcl}[2017/04/13]% Need at least KOMA-Script v3.23
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\FamilyStringKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{hypertarget}{\currenthypertarget}
\newcommand*{\currenthypertarget}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifx\currenthypertarget\@empty
    \def\currenthypertarget{#1.\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \fi  
  \hypertarget{\currenthypertarget}{}\@hangfrom{\hskip
    #2#3}{\pdftooltip{#4}{\#\currenthypertarget}}%
  \global\let\currenthypertarget\@empty
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section[hypertarget={First.Section.Name}]{First Section Name}
\lipsum[1]
\section[hypertarget={Example.Section}]{Example Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section[hypertarget={Final.Section}]{Final Section}
See \hyperlink{First.Section.Name}{the first section} or
\hyperlink{Example.Section}{the second section} or
\hyperlink{Final.Section}{this final section}.
\end{document}
```

With Adobe Reader this second example gives, e.g.,

[image: Bookmarks+Heading+Tooltip]

The example PDF has been made using `scrartcl 2017/04/13 v3.23`.

Comment: SumatraPDF shows the tooltips (damn good). and this lets you list named destinations in pdfs. https://pdfresizer.com/list-named-destinations

Comment: The second one makes the named destination and tooltip, but it is "section.2" and the tooltip is "#section.2". Unfortunately the pdfbookmark is "hypertarget=Example.Section"

Comment: @HenryCrun The bookmarks are from the mandatory argument or from option `tocentry`. But don't forget `headings=optiontotocandhead`.

Comment: Yes that was it, found it in the morning, when I could see again! Could we chat about the second part of my problem, which is to automatically generate the targetname from the sectionname? I assume this line needs replacing: \def\currenthypertarget{#1.\csname the#1\endcsname} with something that calls the compact function in tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376450/ –

Comment: @HenryCrun I don't think, that this makes sense, because then you would again need to change external links to the document whenever the (headings of the) document changes and you wouldn't need the tool tips. So the argument against the automatic numeric labels of `hyperref` wouldn't fit any longer and the whole thing wouldn't make sense. Nevertheless you only need to replace the default case `\def\currenthypertarget{#1.\csname the#1\endcsname}` by something that makes the default target from the (extended) title found in argument 4.

Comment: The problem with editing is not so bad. Most post-release revisions either add new sections, re-order the sections, or change the body text. None of these affect the incoming links. Only the special case of renaming an existing section (or giving a new section a conflicting name) causes breakage. The biggest issue is the latter - conflicting names. it is very easy to imagine many different subsections called "Writing". Your solution already allows manual naming, which is the fallback. As perspective, I might manually put 3 hypertargets in a document with 20-50 [sub]sections.